# Obtener las extensiones instaladas en Chrome

Tags: javascript, extensión-google-chrome

Quiero obtener las extensiones instaladas en *Chrome* usando *JavaScript*.

[image: Ejemplo]

Encontré este código, pero solo muestra los *plugins* instalados:

```
var L = navigator.plugins.length;
document.write(L.toString().bold() + " Plugin(s)".bold());
document.write("<br>");
document.write("Name | Filename | description".bold());
document.write("<br>");
for(var i=0; i<L; i++) {
    document.write(navigator.plugins[i].name);
    document.write(" | ");
    document.write(navigator.plugins[i].filename);
    document.write(" | ");
    document.write(navigator.plugins[i].description);
    document.write(" | ");
    document.write(navigator.plugins[i].version);
    document.write("<br>");
}
```

Comment: ¿Estas haciendo una extensión o solo ejecutando `JS` desde el navegador?

Comment: Solo ejecutando JS desde el navegador

Comment: yo necesito exactamente lo mismo! necesito verificar si la app (extencion) esta instalada en chrome, mediente javascript, desde mi web. Necesito tomar desiciones si esta o no instalada. ¿Hay una forma de obtener el id de una extencion, mediante javascript, de una extencion instalada en chrome?